# Ruby on Rails assign company_id and job_id in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, associations, variable-assignment

Have three  models: Company, Job and JobApplications. When submitting the job form, the company_id *and* job_id *are showing up as nil in the rails console. What's the best way to assign both* company_id *and* job_id values for each job created by a company?

I've added the company_id and job_id to the companies and jobs tables. Within the create method of my jobs model, I've assigned @company_id to the job params and company_id and job_id are still showing as nil after creating a job.

**Controller Actions**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @company = current_user.build_company
 end

 def create
    @job = Job.new
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
 end

private
  def set_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  end

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:avatar, :name, :website, :about)
  end
```

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @job = Job.new(:company_id => params[:id])
    @company_id = params[:job][:company_id]
 end

 def create
    # @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    # @company = @job.company
    @job = Job.create(job_params.merge(user: current_user, company_id: current_user, job_id: @job))
    @company_id = params[:job][:company_id]
 end

private

 def set_job
  @job = Job.find_by(id: params[:id])
   if @job.nil?
     redirect_to jobs_path
   end
 end

 def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:company_name, :company_website, :company_description, :company_avatar, :title, :location, :salary, :job_author, :remote_role, :job_type, :rounds_of_interviews, :start_date, :qualifications, :description, :benefits, :job_id)
 end
```

```
class JobApplicationsController < ApplicationController

 def create
    @job_application = JobApplication.new(job_application_params)
    @job_application.user_id = current_user.id
 end

private

 def set_job
   @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
   #  self.job_id
 end

 def job_application_params
      params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :attachment, :work_for_any_employer, :require_visa_sponsorship)
 end
```

**Models**

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :conversations
    has_many :jobs
    has_many :job_applications, through: :jobs
end
```

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :company, optional: true
    has_many :job_applications, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class JobApplication < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :job

    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :job_id
end
```

Comment: can you show the code where you're making the assignments.

Comment: Above I added the controller actions for the company, job and job_application classes

Comment: `Job.create(job_params.merge(user: current_user, company_id: current_user, ...` in the `JobsController#create`. I doubt that a current user can be both: a `user` and a `company_id`. Can you please double check?

Comment: I updated the variable to ```@job = Job.create(job_params.merge(company_id: @user_id, job_id: @job))``` when creating a new job posting and submitting it, I'm receiving a "User must exist" error